# Can I make imported PS4 games work region free?

Tags: ps4, region-lock

I have bought some used PS4 video games (MGS5, Black ops 3, BattleField 1) from eBay. Will they work region free and will I also be able to play online?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article](https://www.quora.com/Does-the-PlayStation-4-have-a-region-lock-in-games):

> In general, neither digital nor disc-based games will be region locked, but PlayStation recommends that all users purchase games at the region of their residence to guarantee the best overall experience and customer service. In certain instances, a software publisher may choose to region lock a game title for specific reasons, but Sony Computer Entertainment expects these instances to be uncommon.

This is just for the games however. DLC purchases appear to be a different story.  If your Playstation Account is North American, and your game is from Europe, the North American DLC for that game will not work.  As the article words it:

> However, this does not apply to DLC (downloadable content). If you own a North American game, then you would need to purchase the North American DLC for that title in the North American PSN store with a North American PSN ID.

Bottom line, the games should work no problem.  DLC you will have to be careful with.

Comment: Same exact time dang

Comment: @n_palum once again we meet.

Comment: i would like to add that UK and Aus have different Stores such as when Agarest Generations of War came out the Aus Store didn't have the DLC, only the UK Store. alot of the games i buy come from the UK and Aus DLC works with them

Answer (score 1):

I live in the UK and have an american copy of The Last of Us (Remastered). Got it for Christmas off a non-tech-savvy relative.

It worked, kinda, but refused to download the free DLC necessary to play online.

To fix it, I had to create an american account and download the DLC using that account. Now, every time I want to play it, I must first:

- login to american account
- boot up the game
- log into multiplayer
- close game
- log into main account
- boot up game again
- log into multiplayer

Its about 2 minutes of effort once every time I want to play. Annoying, but doable.

I know its not exactly your question but hopefully it helps :)

Comment: Thanks so much for writing this. I was wondering if it was worth it to buy US games cos sometimes they are cheaper than EU ones on Amazon. Specially if the online multiplayer was playable. I see now it's far too much effort to justify buying them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PS4 games are region free, note games from PlayStations 1-3 are not.

[Thread:](https://www.gamespot.com/forums/playstation-nation-1000002/ps4-region-free-playing-restricted-ps1-3-games-on--31513184/)

> "The Playstation 4 is region free. PS4 games from Japan, North
>   America, Oceania, Europe and region 5 South Africa, South America.
>   Will play just fine on your PS4 console. Playstation 1,2,3 games from
>   Playstation Now require an account from the region you live in."

[Also note,](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/691087-playstation-4/68653935) DLC must match the region of the game. According to one person there is a slight change DLC works out of region, but generally it will not.

> "NA DLC + NA GAME = works. NA DLC + JP GAME = probably won't work
>   (though in rare cases DLC will work with copies from different
>   regions, as rule of thumb, most won't) "

Comment: i should point out that that the quote is talking about PS Now PS3 Games. PS3 Games themselves are generally region free as i have US, UK and Aus games and they all work on my Aus PS3. i suspect the "region lock" on PS Now is because it's tied to your PSN Account and works like other PSN brought games on a PS4